# Bulk Insert csv file from FTP server with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv, ftp, bulkinsert

Basically what the title is saying.

Today when I use bulk insert with T-SQL on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to get data from a local drive I use the following query,

```
BULK INSERT tmp_table
FROM 'c:\data\x.csv'
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a' );
```

Which works ok. But now I want to be able to read `.csv` data files from a folder on a FTP server.

As every other FTP server, I need username\password to log in first, and then, I somehow need to fetch the files. Is this possible with T-SQL?

I do know that with C# this would be a piece of cake for me, but want to learn this by using T-SQL.

I will also need to know how I can dynamically get the names of files from a given folder on the FTP server, but since I'm taking this one step at a time, you don't need to answer this right away.

When the files are on local drive i am able to use `xp_dirtree` to get the names of all files in a folder.

An excellent guide can be found here http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files.html

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services has an FTP task that can download a file, and can also connect and bulk insert to a database. In fact, the kind of task you describe is pretty much what it's designed for. That's certainly how I'd do it these days.

Comment: could you tell me how, or point me to some guides ?

Comment: You can find the MSDN doc on SSIS here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx.  This page describes using the FTP task: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms137656.aspx.

Comment: I was wondering if theres a way doing this with only mssql server 2008r2, would like to avoid installing extra software